# How to regain my cats trust after medical care?

Tags: cats

So I’ve been having an issue with my cat trusting me these last few days as we’ve started a new ointment that I have to apply directly to his tail. The very first time was ok but ever since he had be absolutely against me caring for his tail and today even ripped up his scabbing (his tail was relatively recently amputated). I need to be able to apply the ointment but he absolutely despises letting me touch his tail and I’m worried he will continue to be distrustful of me even after his tail is fully healed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a cat likely to be traumatized if it is physically forced to take medicine?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/32912/is-a-cat-likely-to-be-traumatized-if-it-is-physically-forced-to-take-medicine)

Comment: In my experience cats have a tendency to scratch scabbed wounds open again many times until they heal. You need to interact with your cat (pet him, play with him) without touching his tail several times each day to show him that not every interaction is about his tail. In this case it might be worth asking the vet *how important* the ointment is. If it's antibiotic, then you need to apply it. If it's only a moisturizer, it might be enough to apply it only when the opportunity arises.

Comment: It’s to help prevent the itching and make it so he doesn’t have ghost pains after it fully heals. As well as to help while I sleep/work (which is when he has a tendency to bust open the scabbing. Luckily he’s started coming back out to interact with me again but for a while he wouldnt even let me get near him without a struggle.